# Mongoose does not post with express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman

I am experimenting with Mongoose and I have made this little project:

db.js

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/boeken', function(){
    console.log('mongoose connected');
});
module.exports = db;
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./db');
var Boek = require('./models/boeken');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//1. Eenvoudige instructie
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.json({'Gebruik': 'voer een GET of POST-call uit naar /boeken'});
});

//2. POST-endpoint: nieuw boek in de database plaatsen
app.post('/api/boeken', function (req, res, next) {
    var boek = new Boek({
       titel: req.body.titel,
       auteur: req.body.auteur,
       ISBN: req.body.ISBN
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('server gestart op poort 3000');
});
```

models/boeken.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Boek = mongoose.model('Boek', {
   titel: {type: String, required: true},
   auteur: {type: String, required: true},
   ISBN: {type: String, required: true},
   date: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now()}
});
module.exports = Boek;
```

But when I post the following json with `Postman` it just says "Sending.." and in the browser it says `Cannot POST /api/boeken` and does not post the data:

```
{
"titel": "Hey",
"auteur": "You",
"ISBN": "1111"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using `mongod.exe` Daemon in the background.

I am able to reach /api on the browser btw

Comment: Cause you never call `res.end`, it will request forever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to end the request for the post to work:

```
app.post('/api/boeken', function (req, res, next) {
    var boek = new Boek({
       titel: req.body.titel,
       auteur: req.body.auteur,
       ISBN: req.body.ISBN
    });
    boek.save((err, b) => {  
      res.status(201).send(b); // end the request. 
    });
});
```

Also, ensure your client is setting the Content-Type header to application/json.

Comment: Sorry, meant to add that in.

Comment: Thanks a lot his fixed my problem! Makes sense I tried using `.save()` before but it gave me a promise error because I didn't know how to use it.

Comment: You can use promises instead if you like, lmk if you'd like to see that syntax.

Comment: Yes I saw that but this is for my exam tomorrow so I'll rather keep it simple for now and stick to the guide. But thanks I will look into it later!